# Using Git with Cygwin

Tags: github, cygwin

I am attempting to use GitHub in conjunction with my Windows 7 computer running Cygwin. I have managed to get GitHub working fine when I use the "Powershell.exe" that comes with git for windows. I cannot, however, get it to work when I am in Cygwin. The issue seems to be with authentication because every time I try to clone, push or pull I get `Permission denied (publickey).`.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up an SSH key in `~/.ssh` in Cygwin? IIRC, your Cygwin home directory isn’t the same as your actual user folder.

Comment: @minitech: Yes. I copied the files from `C:\Users\Zack\.ssh` into `C:\cygwin\home\Zack\.ssh` and verified via `cd` and `cat` that they were infact there inside of cygwin.

Comment: Is your key password-protected? If so, does it ask you for a password?

Comment: @minitech: Not sure what you mean by my key being password protected... The repository is private so i guess there should be a login required there but no, it never asks for a password.

Comment: No, it would just be your SSH key that was password-protected. It would have asked you to enter a passphrase when generating it. Anyways, try generating a new one in Cygwin and authorizing that one with GitHub.

Comment: @minitech: THANK YOU! You should post that as an answer so I can choose it as my answer. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try generating a new one with Cygwin!